# No matching service worker detected

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I added a service worker to my application using the command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project ng-zero
```

It responded with this in the terminal:

```
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
CREATE ngsw-config.json (441 bytes)
CREATE src/manifest.json (1071 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png (1253 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (1394 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png (1427 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png (1790 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png (3557 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png (5008 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png (792 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png (958 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (3825 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1985 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (2042 bytes)
UPDATE src/index.html (851 bytes)
```

The was no error, only some warnings.

The `app.module.ts` file now contains:

```
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
...
  imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
```

And I haven't touched the `ngsw-config.json` configuration file:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My `main.ts` file contains the following:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.then(
  () => {
  }
)
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

And the `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgZero</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>

<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

The files under the document root:

```
$ ll ng-zero/
total 1,2M
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  42K oct.  18 13:20 3rdpartylicenses.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  14K oct.  18 13:20 4.c1db20ef5bd9add4749b.js
drwxrwxr-x 3 stephane 4,0K oct.  18 13:20 assets/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 5,4K oct.  18 13:20 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  993 oct.  18 13:20 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 847K oct.  18 13:20 main.07ca5763aa8c2813b8c7.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 1,1K oct.  18 13:20 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 3,2K oct.  18 13:20 ngsw.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 132K oct.  18 13:20 ngsw-worker.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  58K oct.  18 13:20 polyfills.eba1d61bda8f41298ad5.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 2,2K oct.  18 13:20 runtime.fa8fa8286609c1c01b2a.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  519 oct.  18 13:20 safety-worker.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  63K oct.  18 13:20 styles.f57681079a43921c301b.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane  519 oct.  18 13:20 worker-basic.min.js
```

I then went to this web page `https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started` and could successfully do all the exercises, thus seeing the service worker doing its job when offline.

I also added this source code in the `app.component.ts` file and I could see it run fine in the mobile browser, as it offered me to load a newer version:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
    this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
      if (confirm('A newer version of the application is available. Load the new version ?')) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But when I open the Chrome browser console, go to the `Application` tab, select the `Manifest` entry, and click on the `Add to homescreen` link, the console displays the following error: `Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest`

In the `manifest.json` file, the `start_url` value is `/`

```
"start_url": "/"
```

I then changed the `start_url` value to `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/` and redeployed, but it complains the `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/manifest.json` is not found (404).

Here is how I build the application:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /stephaneeybert/ng-zero/
```

The application is deployed at `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/`

I'm on `"@angular/cli": "^7.0.0-rc.2"` and `"@angular/core": "^7.0.0-rc.0"`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the app at this URL (https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/)

It seems it works fine.

1. The Service Worker was successfully registered
2. Caching Works
3. and the application works while offline as well.

While testing an Angular app with a service worker installed, you need to take note of the following:

1. always test the application in an incognito window of the browser
2. test on a localhost server or on a server with https support
3. for the app to be fully functional, you would have to visit the site at least twice or refresh once while on the site.

If you haven't, I would recommend you read more on the operation of service workers and how service worker works in angular.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the service worker works fine even off line. But here is the question: did you succeed in adding the app to your home screen ?

Comment: I could now add the app to the home screen of my phone. But I suspect it is because I had changed the start_url value to `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/` and redeployed. I would like now to revert, change it back to `/` and redeploy, and try adding it to the home screen again.

Comment: Indeed, after I reverted the value of `start_url` to `/` the app would not offer adding itself to the homescreen. So I put the value of `start_url` to `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/` again, and again it offers to add itself to the home screen. I conclude that the default `/` value of `start_url` set by the `ng add @angular/pwa --project ng-zero` script, is wrong.

Comment: I did a different test. Instead of having the `/` or the `https://stephaneeybert.github.io/stephaneeybert/ng-zero/` in the `start_url` property, I had an empty one as in `"start_url": ""`. When I then emptied the phone browser cache and reloaded the app, it offered to add it to the home screen. I prefer the empty value as it is not host specific.

Comment: Oh that's right.

that part just determines which page should be loaded.

Read More Here [w3c](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#start_url-member) , [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/manifest-contains-start_url)

Comment: i have tested with `"start_url": ""` and even with `"start_url": "https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa/home"`   but the situation is same...any help will be appretiated